# TestCafe - browser timeout due to a slow loading element

Tags: testing, automated-tests, timeout, testcafe, browser-automation

I've recently started to test my WebApp with TestCafe and have encountered an issue with one of my pages.. the page makes an expensive call to a third party before displaying the info in an element.. this call can take >10 seconds to return.

When testing this page, TestCafe seems to want to wait until this element is loaded before it will carry out the tests (the tests do not reference this element).

My question is if there is a way I can get around this?

I would have expected that instead of calling await on the whole page, calling await on just the specific selectors would have worked, but no joy, even including no awaits still waits for this element to load? Rather confused! Any help would be hugely appreciated!

```
test.before(async t => {
      await t
      .click('button'); //this takes the user to a new page
    })
    ('should be on the correct page after clicking the button', async t => {
      await t
      //this expect wont be tested until the whole page is loaded 
      //(including the very slow element - hence we will time out before this expect is called)
     .expect(Selector('.app-title').innerText).eql('title');
    });
```

Comment: You can try to increase the Selector Timeout option for the whole test run (https://devexpress.github.io/testcafe/documentation/using-testcafe/command-line-interface.html#--selector-timeout-ms) or for a particular assertion (https://devexpress.github.io/testcafe/documentation/test-api/assertions/#assertion-options)

Comment: Thanks for your reply! This is the solution that I've come to to avoid the time outs. Ideally though, instead of waiting for this element to load, I want it to ignore it as it's making my tests so slow! With my small amount of understanding around this I guess that while this element is still loading the DOMContentLoaded event hasn't fired yet, and TestCafe wont run the tests until thats done so I don't know if there's a way around this.

Comment: If this element only increases the page load time and is not required for the page's functionality or your tests, you can decrease the page load timeout: https://devexpress.github.io/testcafe/documentation/using-testcafe/command-line-interface.html#--page-load-timeout-ms